# SVG Path as s circle and modified to halve without its center changed

Tags: svg

I want to use SVG path as a circle where I can modify the same circle without changing its center into an arc. Right now when I am trying to modify SVG path for getting an arc, the center of the path changes and shifts to another position. Is this possible doing with svg path?

Comment: Modify how? By hand? With Javascript?  Show us your path. Show us your JS.

Comment: SVG path is modified by JavaScript but for testing I am modifying manually, If you draw a circle using arc in SVG path and then modify to make it semi circle then center of the SVG path changes. I don't want center of the circle to be changed whenever its modified.

Comment: Add a sample SVG to your question so we know what you are referring to.

Comment: Paul, I have been deviated to other task. I will put a example links once back on the above task.